# How do I properly grab the users profile from Realtime Database to get their username before the cloud function returns?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing Cloud Functions to send my users notifications for when interesting things happen like following, liking, commenting. I have copied & adapted the Firebase tutorial for sending a notification when a change at the followers node is detected, but I need to also query the database to get the follower's account data including their username. I think I am close, but the function doesn't finish in time and I'm having trouble understanding promises. Here is the function:

```
    exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref(`/userFollowers/{followedUid}/{followerUid}`)
        .onWrite((change, context) => {
          const followerUid = context.params.followerUid;
          const followedUid = context.params.followedUid;
          // If un-follow we exit the function

          if (!change.after.val()) {
            return console.log('User ', followerUid, 'un-followed user', followedUid);
          }
          console.log('We have a new follower UID:', followerUid, 'for user:', followedUid);

          // Get the list of device notification tokens.
          const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
              .ref(`/users/${followedUid}/notificationTokens`).once('value');
              console.log('Found the followed user\'s token')

          const userInfo = admin.database().ref(`/users/${followedUid}`).once('value');
          console.log(userInfo)
          const username = userInfo['username'];
          console.log(username);

////////////////// ABOVE is where I'm trying to get the username by reading their account data ///////////////////

          // Get the follower profile.
          const getFollowerProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(followerUid);

          // The snapshot to the user's tokens.
          let tokensSnapshot;

          // The array containing all the user's tokens.
          let tokens;

          return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getFollowerProfilePromise]).then(results => {
            tokensSnapshot = results[0];
            const follower = results[1];

            // Check if there are any device tokens.
            if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
              return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
            }
            console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
            console.log('Fetched follower profile', follower);

            // Notification details.
            const payload = {
              notification: {
                title: 'You have a new follower!',
                body: `{username} is now following you.`,
              }
            };

            // Listing all tokens as an array.
            tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
            // Send notifications to all tokens.
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
          }).then((response) => {
            // For each message check if there was an error.
            const tokensToRemove = [];
            response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
              const error = result.error;
              if (error) {
                console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
                // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
                if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                    error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                  tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
                }
              }
            });
            return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
          });
        });
```

How can I ensure that username will have been made available before it returns? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you don't really get to do anything before the cloud function returns. Here's a fun fun function video on [Promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d7s3spWAzo). Basically, you're passing a function into the promise to be executed when the datasnapshot is retrieved.  Promise.All waits on all promises to finish before running the code you've sent it.  It's all asynchronous.  With that in mind, it looks like you are trying to orchestrate a lot of code to complete. Perhaps there's a better way to structure your calls/DB to avoid most of it?  The Free tier has reasonable execution limits.

Comment: [Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5aeM5dvUpA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmgdxMEHar35Wo26fLWm9BI) has some great videos.  Maybe watch the video on [Firebase for SQL devs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) to learn about flattening your DB

Comment: @JamesPoag The video has helped my understanding a bit. The function is copied straight from Firebase though - I'm sure its a bit over engineered especially with logging. I'm also in the paid tier!

Comment: You're in the paid tier and it's timing out?  Holy cow that's like [540](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas) seconds?  Maybe it's not timing out?

Comment: It isn't timing out! The read for the /user/uid values doesn't return before the rest of the function, so username is never available. I'm trying to understand how to make sure it returns before the rest of the function so it is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I get what you are saying...

These lines of code don't do what you think.  All DB reads are done asynchronous, so...

```
const userInfo = admin.database().ref(`/users/${followedUid}`).once('value');
console.log(userInfo)
const username = userInfo['username'];
console.log(username);
```

[`once` returns a promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once), so `userInfo` is actually a promise to return the data.  You won't get the data until you do a `then`.

More chaining promises I'm afraid... just rename `userInfo` to `userInfoPromise` and add it to your `Promise.All` array.